# How to fix: WARNING in ../core.es5.js Critical dependency: The request of a dependency is an expression

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to use the following zoomable canvas in my project.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@durwella/zoomable-canvas

I have just installed CLI.
I have installed the component as described. I had to change the package.json to

```
"private": true,
```

to make it install.

i had to install rxjs-compat to resolve this error:

```
“Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'rxjs/Observable'”
```

It worked. But now i get this output when i serve:

```
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **
                                                                              u Date: 2019-04-03T09:33:59.480Z
Hash: d2ac8e346cac4ef17eb2
Time: 8710ms
chunk {es2015-polyfills} es2015-polyfills.js, es2015-polyfills.js.map (es2015-polyfills) 284 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.js, main.js.map (main) 13.2 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.js, polyfills.js.map (polyfills) 236 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {runtime} runtime.js, runtime.js.map (runtime) 6.08 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.js, styles.js.map (styles) 16.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.js, vendor.js.map (vendor) 5.34 MB [initial] [rendered]

WARNING in ../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js 5659:15-36
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression

WARNING in ../node_modules/@angular/core/@angular/core.es5.js 5675:15-102
Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Compiled with warnings.
```

What i have learned so far is that i ought to change a small bit of code in the following file:

```
webpack.config.js
```

But what i also have read is that this file doesn't exist anymore in angular. 
I have tried locating it and i can't find it anywhere.

Does anyone know how to solve this error message?
I followed everything in the description of the use of the component.
The project just loads a blank page with the line:

```
Cannot GET /
```

Comment: Follow up. I get the warning: "Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression" no matter what zoom component i download and try to use. I dont know if theres something fundamentally wrong in what im doing. What could be the cause of this?